# Logging exception in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception, log4net, castle-windsor

I have`ASP.Net WebAPI based project & I am using Log4Net to log exception. Here is Exception Handling stuff.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    private ILogger _logger = NullLogger.Instance;

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
       try
       {
          // my stuff
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
            LogException(ex);
       }
    }
}

private void LogException(Exception ex)
{
    var msgParams = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "Message", ex.Message },
        { "StackTrace", ex.StackTrace },
    };
    _logger.Info(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgParams));
}
```

DI Configuration.

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
    container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.Log4net).WithConfig("log4net.xml"));
}
```

My Web.Config

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.WebHost" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>

  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Core" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.0.0" newVersion="3.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Castle.Windsor" publicKeyToken="407dd0808d44fbdc" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.0.0" newVersion="3.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging.Core" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.0" newVersion="3.3.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.1.0" newVersion="3.3.1.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Log4Net.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

    <file value="App.log" />

    <appendToFile value="true" />

    <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />

    <encoding value="utf-8" />

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>

</appender>

<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
</root>
```

**But when any exception occurs & controls enters the catch block neither any log file is created nor the exception is logged.**

What I am missing here??

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.

Comment: You have not shown your castle initialization and registering the different objects - more relevant than the all the assembly binding

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here, and while I know nothing about Log4Net, and say that the `NullLogger` class looks awfully suspicious...

Comment: add to log4net node in your xml `debug=true`, that might give you some clue.

Answer (score 3):

Your logger is `private` and you do not inject this dependency via the constructor. For Castle to inject it via Property Injection it should be public.

You can see more in the [documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/how-properties-are-injected.md).
Castle Windsor's recommendation as a [best practice](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/logging-facility.md#best-practices):

```
private ILogger logger = NullLogger.Instance;

public CustomerService()
{
}

public ILogger Logger
{
   get { return logger; }
   set { logger = value; }
}
```

Comment: If that's the cause then I should get Null Exception

Comment: But in my case neither I am getting any exception nor it is logging any exception

Comment: @Kgn-web - no you won't because a `NullLogger` isn't null. It's a logger that does nothing. A nice way for Castle to enable you to just call the logger without worrying if it is actually set (Because usually loggers are a side business and a class's weak dependency)

Comment: @Kgn-web - If you debug your code you will see that the logger is called and if you check you will see it is not null but a proper object - one can check the implementation but it probably just has empty implementations for the functions

Comment: Let me check again. However I have added MY DI stuff in the post. Please have a look

Comment: I checked. If I remove `private ILogger _logger = NullLogger.Instance;` & update it as `public ILogger _logger;` I gets an error while calling the method as _Object reference not set to an instance of an object._

Comment: @Kgn-web - See update for better understanding. Also how is your controller registered?

Comment: NO mate, still same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139926/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-kgn-web).

Comment: @Kgn-web - Please show how you register your controllers, use the Installer and such. It will help to see how everything is connected